# Postgres 9.6 : Function that returns array of strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, stored-functions

I'm trying to create function that will return array of type text/varchar. Here is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.someFunction(text, text, text)
 RETURNS character varying[]
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
   i text;
   arr_len varchar[];
BEGIN
FOR i in (select string_to_array($1,','))
LOOP
   arr_len := schema.someOtherFunctionThatReturnsText(i::text, $2, $3)::varchar;
END LOOP;
RETURN arr_len;
END
$function$
;
```

This function returns NULL rows all the time. I don't get it why. Any suggestions?

Just to mention that schema.someOtherFunctionThatReturnsText returns text and it works fine.

Comment: "Just to mention that schema.someOtherFunctionThatReturnsText returns text and it works fine."  Please show us.

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense.  It has a loop that cannot actually loop.  Maybe you are missing an UNNEST?  Can you explain to us what you think this function is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This function returns NULL rows all the time. I don't get it why.

You overwriting the value of `arr_len` with every iteration. I am actually surprised that the function works at all as you are assigning a scalar value (single `text` value ) to an array - that should actually throw an error unless that function returns an text array (`text[]`) rather than `text` as the obfuscated name suggests.

You are also using the FOR loop incorrectly. The `select string_to_array()` only returns a single array, it does not loop over the array. Plus the variable should be a record, not a `text` variable.

To [loop over array elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAYhttps://), you need to use `FOREACH`, not a FOR loop with a select. Then you need to append the result of the function call to your result variable. But in order for that to work, you need to initialize the variable first.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(text, text, text)
 RETURNS text[]
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
   i text;
   arr_len text[] := array[]::text[]; -- initialize the array
BEGIN
  FOREACH i in ARRAY string_to_array(p_elements,',')
  LOOP
     arr_len := arr_len || schema.someotherfunctionthatreturnstext(i::text, $2, $3));
  END LOOP;

  RETURN arr_len;
END
$function$
;
```

---

But you are over complicating the whole thing.

You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this:

Just unnest the array you get and using `array_agg()` to assemble the result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.some_function(text, text, text)
 RETURNS text[]
 LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$function$
   select array_agg(schema.someotherfunctionthatreturnstext(x.element, $2, $3)::text)
   from unnest(string_to_array($1,',')) as x(element);
$function$
;
```

---

It would be better if you declared the parameters with a proper array type (e.g. `text[]`) rather than relying on a comma-separated text value. And please use parameter names rather than `$1`, or `$2` so the whole function gets easier to read (and maintain)